# MongoDB $nearSphere not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

Having a hard time understanding trying to return locations that are within a certain distance, in m, from a given point.

Given the following doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548edee849847b6cd7c78de9"),
    "name" : "A",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "place A",
            "position" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    18.0244639, 
                    -18.0455594
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "place B",
            "position" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    28.0244639, 
                    -26.0455594
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "place C",
            "position" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    40.0244639, 
                    -40.0455594
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to return only the location called **place b** above. I am using the following query, but keep getting **place A** returned!

```
db.test.find(
   { "locations.position":{  $nearSphere: { //tried $near too
           $geometry: {
              type : "Point",
              coordinates : [ 28.0244639, -26.0455594 ]
           },
           $maxDistance: 100
        }
     }
   }, 
   {
       _id: 0, 'locations.$': 1
   }
)
```

Comment: Looks like #maxDistance is defined twice in your find. The issue here however is you find will return the entire document and your projection the first array element from that document. $elemMatch may work for this though I have not used it with a nearSphere query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: you should use $geoWithin instead of $near/$nearSphere if you don't care about sorting by distance - $within will be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not get it correct using $near, but did switch back to $geoWithin which is apparently much quicker according to @Asya:

```
db.test.find(
{
   "locations.position": {
      $geoWithin: { $center: [
          [ 28.0244639, -26.0455594], // longitude, latitude
            0.5/6371 // 500m radius 6371
          ] }
   }
},
    {"locations.$": 1} // projection 
)
```